# Send value from Front To Back without changing java methods signature (springboot)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, rest, http

I need to send a value from an Angularjs front to a springboot Java back-office.
The back is called by many other fronts and services.
Which means I can change The front but I have to make sure that any change on the back must not break it for the other callers.

So Extra headers or Other fields in the request body etc... any change that won't break the other existing calls is what I'm looking for.

An example of some methods signature:

A HTTP GET signature

```
@Override
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Something>> getSomething(
        @RequestHeader(name = Constants.HEADER.SOME_CODE) final String code,
        @RequestHeader(name = Constants.HEADER.COMPANY_ID) final String companyId,
        @RequestHeader(name = Constants.HEADER.CLIENT_ID) final String clientId) {
```

A HTTP POST signature

```
@Override
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/{pathValue}/transactions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> requestSomething(
        @RequestHeader(name = Constants.HEADER.EFS_CODE) final String vode,
        @RequestHeader(name = Constants.HEADER.COMPANY_ID) final String companyId,
        @RequestHeader(name = "Access-Code", required = false) final String codeAcces,
        @RequestHeader(name = Constants.HEADER.CLIENT_ID) final String clientId,
        @PathVariable("pathValue") final String pathValue,
        @RequestBody @Valid Transact transaction) {
```

Comment: What exact change do you want to make? Extra headers? Other fields in the request body? Please edit your question to include more details on the exact change you want to make.

Comment: The back-office is called by a lot of other services, any change that won't break those existing calls is what i'm looking for :)

Comment: If i add a non required header in the back for example, will the change be transparent for it's other callers ?

Comment: what do you want to do with your angular client? give an exemple of an action you want to perform without changing the back, all those values can be empty except transaction (which may have validation rules), so you are not force to send all those values